# Using a GUID string in TagBuilder.GenerateID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I used this article to create an Image helper:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs.  It says it replaces periods, but has no mention of other limitations.

It all works fine unless I try using GUID string as the id.

The Razor code:

```
@Html.Image(id, ....) //passes a GUID string to helper fine
```

The ImageHelper is exactly as the webpage describes:

```
builder.GenerateId(id);
//breakpoint after this shows the builder object 
//does not create an id attribute when id is a GUID string.
//using id.ToString() doesn't work for GUIDs either
```

Using the GUID string in MergeAttributes works fine:

```
builder.MergeAttribute("title", id); //the GUID string is img title no problem
builder.MergeAttribute("class", id); //the GUID string is class as expected
```

Is there some limitation or workaround when using GUID strings as an ID?

Comment: Guid isn't a string it's a struct. Try Guid.ToString('N'), gives you a string wth no braces or hyphens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs must start with a letter, not a number.  Often, a GUID will start with a number, hence the problem.  `TagBuilder.GenerateId` calls `CreateSanitizedId`, which performs this check:

```
if (!TagBuilder.Html401IdUtil.IsLetter(c1))
    return (string) null;
```

Your best bet is to just add a prefix, like "guid" or something to the beginning of the ID.

Comment: +1 I like that - the prefix I mean - the simple solutions are the best eh?

Comment: @PreetSangha For sure.  Thanks a bunch Kirk, I guess I never tried to make an ID start with a number before.